# Python integer to letter grade issue

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

I am attempting to troubleshoot the errors in this piece of code:

```
import time

while1 = True

def grader (z):
    if   z >= 0 or z <= 59:
        return "F"
    elif z >= 60 or z <= 62:
        return "D-"
    elif z >= 62 or z <= 66:
        return "D"
    elif z >= 67 or z <= 69:
        return "D+"
    elif z >= 70 or z <= 62:
        return "C-"
    elif z >= 73 or z <= 76:
        return "C"
    elif z >= 77 or z <= 79:
        return "C+"   
    elif z >= 80 or z <= 82:
        return "B-"
    elif z >= 83 or z <= 86:
        return "B"
    elif z >= 87 or z <= 89:
        return "B+"
    elif z >= 90 or z <= 92:
        return "A-"
    else:
        return "A"



while while1:
    z = int(input("I will tell you the grade of this number, enter from 1 - 100\n"))
    if z < 0 or z > 100:
        print "Between 1 and 100 PLEASE!\n"
        while1 = True
    print grader(z)
    print "New number now\n"
    time.sleep(100)
    while1 = True
```

The argument in this situation is the integer `z`. `z`'s value is set by the user and then the function should swing in and determine what letter grade `z` is worth, no matter what though it always returns 'F.'

This is rather befuddling to me (I am a novice) and I could use some assistance.

Comment: Code review nitpick:  If someone uses grader wrong, they get an A.  You should throw an error or return something else if input is not between 1 and 100.

Comment: `z >= 90 or z <= 92` should be using `and`, and once corrected, can be expressed as `90 <= z <= 92`.

Comment: upon `return`, there is no need for the `elif`. `if z <= 59` etc. is  sufficient.

Comment: and `while while1` is simply `while True`. don't hide that. you don't need all these flags - just use `break` to finish the loop.

Comment: I don't think `or` means what you think it means

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is this:

```
if   z >= 0 or z <= 59:
```

Use:

```
if 0 <= z <= 59:
```

This alleviates the problem you're having using `or` instead of `and` and is more readable.

But you should look at the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples) module:

```
>>> def grade(score, breakpoints=[60, 70, 80, 90], grades='FDCBA'):
        i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
        return grades[i]

>>> [grade(score) for score in [33, 99, 77, 70, 89, 90, 100]]
['F', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: I suspect this is an assignment and not real life ... I doubt the teach will take the bisect solution... but yeah +1 all the same

Comment: @JoranBeasley well - it's from the docs, so I'm hoping the student is expected to read those ;)

Comment: I think you should note about the mutable default arg, or simply use `tuple`.

Comment: @Elazar since it's not mutated - I don't really think it's a big deal - and since I don't really expect it to be used, that's another concept the OP probably doesn't want thrown upon them at the current time

Answer (score 2):

Your `or`s in `grader` should be `and`s. Anything you input that is greater than 0 will pass the first conditional, and so will be an F.

Comment: Directly answers why it's always an `F` +1

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jon Clements' (great) answer, but I think easier to undestand:

```
def grade(score, breakpoints, grades):
    for k, v in zip(breakpoints, grades):
        if score > k:
            return v
    return 'Error'

grade(score, breakpoints=(90, 80, 70, 60, 0), grades=('A','B','C','D','E','F'))
```

Comment: You should make this discern sub-grades, e.g. `A+` vs `A` vs `A-`.

Comment: @MarcLaugharn It's too verbose. but with tuples you can extend it easily.

Answer (score 0):

`if x>0 or x < 59` will cover everything over 0

you are confusing ors with ands

`if x>0 and x < 59` is only the range from 0 to 59

but can be more succinct as 
`0 < x < 59`

Comment: that's `<=`. probably better round it up anyway - `< 60`

Answer (score 0):

This has long since been solved, but a few points remain:

1. no need to set `while1 = True` again and again.
2. 0 is a valid input in your code, but the text says that valid grades start at 1.

A complete solution, combined with [@Jon Clement's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907384/1587329), would be

```
import time
from bisect import bisect

def grader(score,
           breakpoints=[60, 62, 67, 70, 73, 77, 80, 83, 87, 90, 93],
           grades=['F', 'D-', 'D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-',
                   'A']):
        i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
        return grades[i]

while True:
    z = int(input("I will tell you the grade of this number, enter from 1 - 100\n"))
    if z < 0 or z > 100:
        print "Between 0 and 100 PLEASE!\n"
        continue
    print grader(z)
    time.sleep(100)
    print "New number now\n"
```