# How to change an integer value to a letter python

Tags: python

So i am making a program that totals your grade for the first semester and will do the same for the second semesters. Here is what i have and it is extremely simple...

```
a = raw_input('1st Quarter: ')
b = raw_input('2nd Quarter: ')
c = raw_input('Midterm: ')
d = a * 0.4
e = b * 0.4
f = c * 0.2
g = a + b + c
print 'Your semester grade is', g
```

I would like to know if there was a piece of code where i could take the variable `g` and change it from a number to a variable or in this case it would be a grade such as A, B, C, D, or F. I was thinking i could do

```
if g in [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
    print 'your grade is A'
```

I would do more for B-F's But this did not work. I have looked into it and could not find much on it and what i did find did not help or was not right!

Comment: You can check `if 90 <= g <= 100`.

Comment: this is simple `if g in xrange(90,100+1): #do stuff` or Falkos which I'd prefer more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a very similar example [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/bisect.html#other-examples) using the bisect function:

```
def grade(score, breakpoints=[60, 70, 80, 90], grades='FDCBA'):
    i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
    return grades[i]
```

So, in Python3, you could do something like:

```
import bisect

GRADES = 'FDCBA'
GRADE_THRESHOLDS = (60, 70, 80, 90)


def grade(score):
    i = bisect.bisect(GRADE_THRESHOLDS, score)
    return GRADES[i]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(input('1st Quarter: '))
    b = int(input('2nd Quarter: '))
    c = int(input('Midterm: '))
    weighted = a * 0.4 + b * 0.4 + c * 0.2
    final_grade = grade(weighted)
    print('Your semester grade is', final_grade)
```

Of course, you'll want to replace the tuple of thresholds with values that make sense for your grading scheme.

Comment: Although it's not a problem in _this_ function, I can feel my teeth itch whenever I see a mutable container like a list used as a default parameter.  It would work just as well with `breakpoints=(60, 70, 80, 90)`.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the example program (though note that the original grade function is copied from the python docs).

Comment: I see no problem using a list

Comment: I know it's a _faux pas_ for the author to ask about downvotes, but I would love to know why this answer got slammed so hard in its first few minutes.  Even before the edits, it solved the problem.  A [very similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16907384/4116239) got only upvotes.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I downvoted on the original revision which had no explanation and didn't include the import. I just removed mine.

Answer (score 1):

The following program demonstrates how to convert an integer value to a letter grade in Python:

```
import math
import sys


def main():
    weights = (('1st Quarter', 2), ('2nd Quarter', 2), ('Midterm', 1),
               ('3rd Quarter', 3), ('4th Quarter', 3), ('Final', 4))
    weighted_score = get_weighted_score(weights)
    min_grade_scores = dict(A=90, B=80, C=70, D=60, F=0)
    grade = pick_grade(weighted_score, min_grade_scores)
    print('Your semester grade is', grade)


def get_weighted_score(weights):
    total_score = total_weight = 0
    for name, weight in weights:
        score = get_integer(name + ': ', 0, 100)
        total_score += score * weight
        total_weight += weight
    return round(total_score / total_weight)


def get_integer(prompt, min_value=-math.inf, max_value=math.inf):
    while True:
        try:
            value = input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            if not value:
                print('Please provide a value')
                continue
            try:
                number = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                print('Please provide a number')
            else:
                if number < min_value:
                    print('Number may not be lower than', min_value)
                    continue
                if number > max_value:
                    print('Number may not be higher than', max_value)
                    continue
                return number


def pick_grade(weighted_score, min_grade_scores):
    pairs = map(lambda pair: pair[::-1], min_grade_scores.items())
    for score, grade in sorted(pairs, reverse=True):
        if weighted_score >= score:
            return grade
    raise ValueError('Valid grade could not be found')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In particular, you will want to look at the `pick_grade` function to see how the algorithm works.